# I am not manage height of expantionTile Widget

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation, expansion

I have faced the issue of height related actually I am using the expansion tile widget. there is according to UI height not managed and not working so please explain to any mentor and friends or brother

I want it according to the UI height manage widget.

Comment: Add  your code snippet what you try?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can use SizedBox widget to manage height
SizedBox(
height://but here the height
),

if you want to know screen height you can use MediaQuery.of(context).size.height.

Comment: maybe you are not understand my questions sir

Comment: Please provide enough code so I can better understand

Answer (score 0):

You can use size box :
This will set the height of the widget to 100.

```
  SizedBox(
  height: 100,
  child: YourWidget(),
)
```

Use the Expanded widget: You can use the Expanded widget to make a widget take up all the available space in its parent :

```
    Expanded(
        child: myCustomWidget(),
          )
```

Also SingleChildScrollView

```
    SingleChildScrollView(
  child: YourWidget(),
)
```

You can also use ConstrainedBox

```
   ConstrainedBox(
  constraints: BoxConstraints(
    minHeight: 100,
    maxHeight: 200,
  ),
  child: YourWidget(),
)
```

I hope above example will help you.

Answer (score 0):

--> you can use of sizedBox to given fix sized for expantionTile widgets.

-- either then you can use expanded widgets to given heigh for according your screen.

```
SizedBox(
  height: 150,
  child: ExpantionTile(),
),
   
Expanded(
  child: ExpantionTile(),
),
```